# Is there any way to monitor Resource Health for Azure Kubernetes Service using an API

Tags: azure, api, azure-aks

I am trying to monitor Azure Services using their supported Resource Health APIs. Apparently for Azure Kubernetes Service, this is not supported.
Is it possible to check the availability of this Service using an api ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor now support to monitor the Azure Container Service(AKS). You can see the [Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcontainerservicemanagedclusters) that the Azure Monitor support for AKS. Also, you can get all the service that [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcontainerservicemanagedclusters).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I need to check the Service availability using the Resource Health API, but AKS is not supported yet using this method.Is there any other way to check its availability using another API/SDK ? Thanks

Comment: Unluck, it seems there is no other API/SDK to check if the service is supported in Azure Monitor as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your response again. But how can we reach that using any programming language? I am no AKS expert so I wouldn't know how to start as a beginning.

Comment: When you know which can use with the monitor from the support page, then you can just set it in the code without checking its availability.

Answer (score 0):

No, AKS is not integrated with Azure Resource Health yet, but it is on our roadmap for the next 6 months (I'm the lead PM for AKS).

In the interim, the only alternative would be to ping the Kubernetes API server for the cluster. If the API server is responsive and all the nodes in the cluster are in a Ready state, you can consider the cluster healthy.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are currently using AKS for our applications and we need to implement the necessary monitoring. Can you please explain more on your suggestion, how can i ping or GET/POST from the Kubernetes API server  and get the cluster health? Any links/doc or previous similar implementations would be very helpful. Thanks.